# Rendering react-bootstrap component causing errors

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to add the react-bootstrap accordion to my react website. However, when I add it all I see is a white screen on the page that contains the accordion. I've installed react-bootstrap and bootstrap with npm. After refreshing the page I get the error:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion'

class Collapsible extends Component{
  
  render() {
    return(
      <section className="container">
        <Accordion>
          <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
            <Accordion.Header>Accordion Item #1</Accordion.Header>
            <Accordion.Body>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
              tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
              veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
              commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
              velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
              cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
              est laborum.
            </Accordion.Body>
          </Accordion.Item>
        </Accordion>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Collapsible;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using version 4.x (1.6.x) of `react-bootstrap`, but the components you are using are in version 5.x (2.x) of `react-bootstrap`.

[Version 4 Accordion](https://react-bootstrap-v4.netlify.app/components/accordion/)

Has `Accordion`, `Accordion.Toggle`, and `Accordion.Collapse` components.

```
<Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
  <Card>
    <Card.Header>
      <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
        Click me!
      </Accordion.Toggle>
    </Card.Header>
    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
      <Card.Body>Hello! I'm the body</Card.Body>
    </Accordion.Collapse>
  </Card>
  <Card>
    <Card.Header>
      <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="1">
        Click me!
      </Accordion.Toggle>
    </Card.Header>
    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
      <Card.Body>Hello! I'm another body</Card.Body>
    </Accordion.Collapse>
  </Card>
</Accordion>
```

[Version 5 Accordion](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/#api)

Has the `Accordion`, `Item`, `Header`, and `Body` components.

```
<Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
  <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
    <Accordion.Header>Accordion Item #1</Accordion.Header>
    <Accordion.Body>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
      veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
      velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
      cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
      est laborum.
    </Accordion.Body>
  </Accordion.Item>
  <Accordion.Item eventKey="1">
    <Accordion.Header>Accordion Item #2</Accordion.Header>
    <Accordion.Body>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
      veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
      velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
      cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
      est laborum.
    </Accordion.Body>
  </Accordion.Item>
</Accordion>
```

Here's a running codesandbox of your code running in version 2.0.0-beta.6 of `react-bootstrap`.

[image: Edit rendering-react-bootstrap-component-causing-errors]

Comment: I updated my version of react-bootstrap and imported the correct css and it worked.